# How to identify first appearance of items in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe provided below. I need to create a new column with label as `'New'` for the first occurrence of a product if it appeared only in the year 2021, and `'old'` otherwise. I am using pyspark.

Input:

```
desc  year
0  a  2019
1  a  2020
2  a  2020
3  b  2020
4  b  2019
5  b  2021
6  c  2021
7  a  2021
8  c  2021
9  e  2020
```

Output:

```
   desc  year    Label
0  a  2019      old
1  a  2020      old
2  a  2020      old
3  b  2020      old
4  b  2019      old
5  b  2021      old
6  c  2021      New
7  a  2021      old
8  c  2021      New
9  e  2020      old
```

If the product appeared for the first time in the year 2021 with no history then we need to label the product as New.

Data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('a','2019')
    ,('a','2020')
    ,('a','2020')
    ,('b','2020')
    ,('b','2019')
    ,('b','2021')
    ,('c','2021')
    ,('a','2021')
    ,('c','2021')
    ,('e','2020')
  ], ['desc', 'year'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the min of `year` over a window partitioned by product (`desc`), and then check that the result is equal to `2021`. Finally, to get the desired label instead of a boolean, you may use the `when` function.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
win = Window.partitionBy('desc')
df.withColumn("New", f.min(f.col("year")).over(win) == "2021")\
  .withColumn("New", f.when(f.col("New"), "New").otherwise("old"))\
  .show()
```

```
+----+----+---+
|desc|year|New|
+----+----+---+
|   a|2019|old|
|   a|2020|old|
|   a|2020|old|
|   a|2021|old|
|   b|2020|old|
|   b|2019|old|
|   b|2021|old|
|   c|2021|New|
|   c|2021|New|
|   e|2020|old|
+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I was answered the same question but cannot find. Anyway, you can use the `first` function to find the first year and just ckeck whether it is `2021` or not.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('desc')

df.withColumn('label', f.when(f.first('year').over(w) == f.lit('2021'), f.lit('new')).otherwise(f.lit('old'))) \
  .show()

+----+----+-----+
|desc|year|label|
+----+----+-----+
|   e|2020|  old|
|   c|2021|  new|
|   c|2021|  new|
|   b|2020|  old|
|   b|2019|  old|
|   b|2021|  old|
|   a|2019|  old|
|   a|2020|  old|
|   a|2020|  old|
|   a|2021|  old|
+----+----+-----+
```